# Calendar control using System Windows Forms Calendar C# Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, calendar, scheduling

Hi guys I am trying to look for Calendar control on C# but I cannot find it anywhere I am using Visual Studio 10 and 12. I will upload the problems that I am facing (I am looking for a scheduling calendar).

Can anyone possibility help me so I know how I would be able to add this kind of calendar into my form.

I am looking calendar control on choose items. You can find it on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAPxOTBmaWc but not on my visual studio.
[1. It does not recognise it 2. Also here I cannot find it 3. In that video it shows I should be able to find it on "choose items" but on mine I cannot find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr7KS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube Video is a Viscomsoft Tutorial. So search [Viscomsoft](http://www.viscomsoft.com/) by Google. They provide third party controls. So do the following:

1. Go to my link above
2. Buy the products you need
3. Install the third party software
4. Watch your toolbox

This is no built in Visual Studio functionality. If you want to add third party .dll to your toolbox make sure you add the link to your project. Then go to toolbox->right click->add element and select the .dll.

Hope this helps ;)